# Calendar icon for UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

Does anyone know where I can get a calendar template icon like the one in Reminders for Mac? Or do I have to create one myself…=(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use icons, there are lots of sites that you can get icons for commercial or non-commercial use. Such as:

http://www.iconfinder.com/

http://www.findicons.com/

Comment: Thanks…those types of icons weren't what I was looking for; I just created my own.